# Swift: how to flush stdout after println?

Tags: swift

How do I flush the stdout in Swift after a `println` command?

That is, what is the Swift equivalent of `fflush(stdout)` in C?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe the following works (it compiles and builds, but I have not tried it, though):

Place `#import <stdio.h>` in your bridging header file

In your code use:

`fflush(__stdoutp)`

Answer (score 22):

You can use

```
fflush(stdout)
```

after you import libc:

```
#if os(Linux)
    import Glibc
#else
    import Darwin.C
#endif
```

Comment: Also useful for flushing XCTest error messages so they don't mix up with regular prints. (Comment for helping Google find this.)

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to flush to stdout automatically instead of manually calling `fflush(__stdoutp)` after every `println`, you can disable buffering altogether.

`setbuf(__stdoutp, nil);`