# How to grep the stdout of a macOS console app that uses RunLoop

Tags: swift, macos, grep, console-application, nsrunloop

Here a simple Swift code for a macOS console app:

```
import Foundation

print("hello world")
RunLoop.main.run()
```

In my real code, I use `RunLoop` to avoid leaving the console app, because I react to some CoreBluetooth events and have an infinite loop of things I want to display. I just want to quit the app using Ctrl+C.

However, when using `RunLoop.main.run()` I cannot grep the output any more in my terminal:

```
$ ./app
hello world
^C
$ ./app | grep hello
^C
```

Some ideas about how I can grep the output?
I guess the usage of `RunLoop` is a bad idea, but what can be the alternative without having a kind of active wait or manually manage some execution threads?

Comment: Could it be that it works fine, but the output needs a call to flush?

Comment: I am not exactly sure to understand since there is a screen output, however I added a `fflush(stdout)` line and it works better. If you rewrite your suggestion as an answer instead of a comment, I will be able to upvote it at the very minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to either flush stdout:

```
fflush(__stdoutp)
```

or set the buffer size on stdout to zero (makes it fast, but using more resources):

```
setbuf(__stdoutp, nil)
```

See [Swift: how to flush stdout after println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171362/swift-how-to-flush-stdout-after-println)

This is typically the solution, when you see output to the terminal, but no output once you pipe the process into another one, like grep. The piping affects the default choice for buffering. Hope this helps!